# Que hace o que es Q_OBJECT en Qt 5.x

Tags: c++, qt

Al crear una aplicación con QUI usando el asistente de Qt Creator este me crea una clase para la ventana, parecida a esta:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Mi pregunta es: el código que aparece al inicio de la clase, más precisamente `Q_OBJECT`, ¿Que es esto?, ¿Para que me sirve o que hace?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt es un framework que trabaja sobre C++. Este framework incluye una serie de características que no están soportadas nativamente por el propio lenguaje:

- Metadatos
- Señales

Para poder ofrecer estas herramientas, Qt incorpora una etapa antes de compilar que genera unos ficheros con código complementario a tus clases... se trata de la generación de MOCs. Estos ficheros incorporan tanto la información de metadatos (que permite inspeccionar el objeto en tiempo de ejecución), como el mecanismo de señales. En tiempo de compilación estos ficheros se añaden al proyecto para que todo funcione como se espera.

Ahora bien, ni todos los objetos van a tener metadatos ni tampoco señales. La decisión de quien sí y quien no la proporciona la macro `Q_OBJECT`. Si no incluyes esta macro tu objeto se parecerá más a uno propio de C++ que a uno de Qt, lo cual no es malo salvo que ese objeto necesite hacer uso de señales o metadatos.

Por cierto, un requisito indispensable para que la macro `Q_OBJECT` pueda hacer su trabajo es que el objeto herede antes o después de `QObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Es un metadato de QT que sirve para activar la funciones de eventos en un objeto QT es decir el uso de Signals y Slots.

Documentacion de QT al respecto del tema

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html#meta-object-system